# Create a dynamic string based on checkbox input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes in a table on a page. What I am trying to do is when the user is clicking on the checkbox, its value would be printed below the table. Multiple values can be printed in line, separated by '+':

```
"a+b+c+d"
```

I have this code in the base_pro.html:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}Offer engineering{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/reset-min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block script %}
    <script src="/static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/my_jq.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">{% block header %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="messages-wrap">
      <div id="messages">
        {% for category, msg in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
          <p class="message flash-{{ category }}">{{ msg }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">{% block footer %}{% endblock %}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.html:

```
{% extends "base_pro.html" %}
{% block content %}
Hi {{ user.name }}!

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>v1</th>
<th>v2</th>
<th>v3</th> 
<th>v4</th>
<th>v5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="offers" />a</label></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="offers" />b</label></td> 
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="offers" />c</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="d" class="offers" />d</label></td>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

my_js.js:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
var arr = []
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     arr.push($(this).val())
   }
})
var vals = arr.join("+")
var str = vals
console.log(str);

})
```

I can't get the string to show up when the checkboxes are checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to better understand your question - by "show up", do you mean on the main screen or console? It's printing correctly to console.

Comment: @J. Chen main screen

Comment: you need to inject the concatenated string value in the DOM explicitly

Comment: @KaushalNiraula how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an empty div below your table that will display the value when the checkboxes are activated. I put a solution below.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
var arr = []
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     arr.push($(this).val())
   }
})
var vals = arr.join("+");
var str = vals;
$("#val").text(str);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>v1</th>
<th>v2</th>
<th>v3</th> 
<th>v4</th>
<th>v5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="offers" />a</label></td>
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="offers" />b</label></td> 
<td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="offers" />c</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="d" class="offers" />d</label></td>
</table>
<div id="val"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject the concatenated string value in the DOM explicitly 
Say theres a div below the table

After `var vals = arr.join("+")`, you can insert that value inside the above `div` as

```
$('#displayConcatenatedString').html(vals)
```

Comment: Still not showing up. Could it be that it does not see the .js file?

Comment: That was just an example. You need to have a div after the table(eg with an id `displayConcatenatedString`)